# css animation with two steps and no transition

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm working on a `css` animation to switch the background color of an element.

This animation is only two phases and no smooth transitions between both phases.

It means, the first 50% of the animation, the background color will be `blue`, and the last 50% of the animation, the background color will be `grey`, without an transition in between.

Here's the animation fully working:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  animation: bg 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes bg {
  0% {
    background: blue;
  }
  50% {
    background: blue;
  }
  50.00001% {
    background: grey;
  }
  100% {
    background: grey;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to do that. What I'm looking for is to use only `from` and `to` inside the `keyframes` without any additional step.

Comment: If either solution helped you, consider marking it as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the side of the corresponding answer.

Answer (score 12):

You can achieve it using the `animation-timing-function: steps(1)` as given in below snippet. You can find more details about the `animation-timing-function` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) and the generic `steps` value [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/single-transition-timing-function) in MDN.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  animation: bg 4s steps(1) infinite;
}

@keyframes bg {
  0% {
    background: blue;
  }
  50% {
    background: grey;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Note:** I have set the keyframe for `grey` color at `50%` instead of `100%` due to the problem discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542789/css3-animate-color-by-steps/37543614#37543614).

Comment: Thanks for the "Note:".  That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a short-cut notation :

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  animation: bg 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes bg {
  from, 50% {
    background: blue;
  }
  50.00001%, to {
    background: grey;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```